# Get and read file via input HTML through AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to receive an input file from HTML input through ajax with PHP... 
Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="file-form-real" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input  type="file" class="inputfile" id="carga-excelreal" name="carga-excelreal" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"><label for="carga-excelreal"><img src="img/MSExcel_2013_logo.svg"><span>Carga Archivo Costo Real</span></label><button type="submit" class="u-button" id="ubutton-real" onclick="uploadManager.sendReal();">Actualizar BD</button></form>
```

Here is the Javascript file uploadManager.js:

```
var uploadManager = {
    sendReal: function(){
        var form = document.getElementById("carga-excelreal");
        var nameOr = form.value;
        var splited = nameOr.split("\\");
        var largo = splited.length;
        var name = splited[largo-1];
        var file = form.files;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('name', name);

        var ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
              url:"controllers/admin/UploadCostoReal.php",
              data: formData, 
              type:"POST",
              contentType:false,
              processData:false,
              cache:false,
              success:function(response){
                  console.log(response);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($file,"../../docs/costo_real/".$name)){
        $msg = "Uploaded Ok";
        echo json_encode($msg, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }else{
        $msg = "There was an error";
        echo json_encode($msg, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
?>
```

When print with print_r($_POST) and print_r($_FILES) here is the output:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [file] => [object FileList]
    [name] => 1557 - Planilla Gestion de Compras 16.ago.2016.xls
)
```

I have the following questions:

-How can I read [object FileList], get the file and save it to a specific folder.

-(I've already saw that [file] is empty, .... why??, it is suposed to have the file).

-The general procedure is ok or I have to do with an action attribute in my form tag???

Also it might very helpful if someone knows how to put a loading gif (this last thing is not important as the main thing I've asked)

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Answer (score 0):

In your js `var file = form.files;` probably needs to be:

`var file = form.files[0];` or `var file = form.files.shift();`

I believe `form.files` will be an array.